# Concentration of posterior probability around a tiny fraction of the prior volume

Tags: pr.probability, it.information-theory, bayesian-probability

In the context of approximating the evidence $Z$ in a Bayesian inference setting
$$
Z = \int d\theta \mathcal L (\theta)\pi (\theta)
$$
with $\mathcal L$ the likelihood, $\pi$ the prior, John Skilling's paper on Nested Sampling [1] (something analogous can be found in [2]) claims the following:

> The integral for $Z$ is dominated by wherever the bulk of the posterior mass is to be found.
> Typically, this occupies a small fraction $e^{-H}$ of the prior, where $H = \rm information = \int \log(dP/dX) dP$.
> $H$ is (minus) the logarithm of that fraction of prior mass that contains the bulk of the posterior
> mass, and it may well be of the order of thousands or more in practical problems where the
> likelihood is concentrated in some obscure corner of the prior domain.

where $dX$ was previously defined to be an element of prior volume $dX=\pi(\theta)d\theta$ and $dP$ is the posterior.

The question is: **what motivates the statement about the fraction of volume?** Is there any proof or intuitive argument to show it?

#### My guesses so far

- Concentration within a volume $e^{-\rm entropy}$ looks a lot like what happens for the typical set of sequences of $n$ i.i.d. random variables (e.g. [3] chapter 3).
  Is something equivalent happening here?
- [This answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/467693/268623) defines the typical set of a posterior distribution $p$ as the space of parameters for which $\log (p/\pi)$ deviates from its expectation $H=\int d\theta p(\theta)\log\frac{p(\theta)}{\pi(\theta)}$ (the same quantity as above) by more than some $\epsilon$.
  But can we argue that $\log (p/\pi)$ is actually concentrating around its expectation?
  Perhaps it is in some limit?

#### References

[1] Skilling, John. "[Nested sampling for general Bayesian computation](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bayesian-analysis/volume-1/issue-4/Nested-sampling-for-general-Bayesian-computation/10.1214/06-BA127.full)." 2006.

[2] Skilling, John. "Bayesian computation in big spaces-nested sampling and Galilean Monte Carlo." 2012.

[3] Thomas M. Cover and Joy A. Thomas. "[Elements of Information Theory](http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/%7Ecgong821/Wiley.Interscience.Elements.of.Information.Theory.Jul.2006.eBook-DDU.pdf)." 2006.